# Шифрование Proxmox

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте. Есть настроеный сервер Proxmox на котором установлен hdd 1TB, который нужно зашифровать. С помощью LUKS попробовал зашифровать, но проблема вот в чем: На диске создан LVM в котором есть группа test, а когда Proxmox создает виртуальную машину то он сам создаем логические тома созданной машины и с помощью LUKS не получаеться зашифровать как так LUKS сам создает логические диски. Подскажите какие еще есть варианты шифрование LUKS+LVM.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!
Вам необходимо зашифровать раздел LUKS, а затем на уже шифрованном разделе создать vg и отдать vg проксмоксу как сторедж. Пример конфигурации если диск не загрузочный:

1. Шифруем раздел `cryptsetup create sdbcrypt /dev/sdb1`
2. Подключаем зашифрованный раздел `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 crypt`
3. Создаем физический раздел на зашифованном диске `lvm pvcreate /dev/mapper/crypt`
4. Создаем группу томов `lvm vgcreate pveStorage /dev/mapper/crypt`
5. Ищем в гуях проксмокса нашу группу томов и добавляем как раздел (storage)

Затем при создании виртуального диска проксмокс сам будет нарезать lv в нашей группе томов. Едиственное что нужно помнить что после ребута надо подключить шифрованный раздел и посмотреть на месте ли группа. (но это можно решить тоже через /etc/fstab).